# Mazur secret Bourbaki report "Analyse p-adique"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request

Does anyone happen to know if a scan of Mazur's report exists, and, if so, where to find it? It appears in the references for Katz's "Higher congruences" and "Eisenstein measure" papers.

Comment: Apparently it's been too long since I've asked a question and I've forgotten where to find the "Community Wiki" option... Help?

Comment: The CW option for questions was removed upon migration in 2013.  Now only moderators can switch it.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I have it. Mazur gave me a xerox copy off his shelf when I asked him (in grad school) if a copy exists. It's 56 pages and the first sentence is: L'objet de ce rapport est de construire la série L p-adique de Kubota-Leopold et d'établir quelques propriétés fondamentales. It was in my office and I was going to try scanning it this evening, but literally as soon as I stepped into the elevator to go to the scanning machine a fire alarm went off in the building. So I had to leave. On my way out someone said he saw smoke in the hallway of the physics wing of the building. But even if the whole place burns down, fear not! I took Mazur's paper with me. You'll get a scan in the next few days.

Update 1: A scan has now been made, and my department's building did not burn down.

Update 2: I sent the scan to Mazur, who has posted it on his homepage at the "Older Material" link, so everyone can get a copy for themselves. A direct link to the scan on his homepage is [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~mazur/papers/Analyse.pdf).

Comment: OK, so we are dealing with a secret text (talked about but never seen) the mere intention of copying triggers a mysterious fire. Could I ask for a copy too?

Comment: @Olivier, sure.

Comment: What's the copywrite status of this? Could it just be posted to ArXiv?

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks for your heroic dedication to the spread of knowledge! Hope the physicists didn't burn down your office though...

Comment: @DanielMoskovich Barry Mazur is not dead, far from it, in fact he even has a webpage where posts preprints sometimes. I'd suggest that Keith email Barry the scanned pdf so he can put it on his webpage or on the arxiv if he wants.

Comment: For some reason I am reminded of the plot (or, perhaps, the McGuffin) of _The Name Of The Rose_

Comment: @YemonChoi: But there was sex between monks (in exchange for a book) in _The Name of the Rose_, hehe. (At least in the novel; I didn't see the movie version.)

Comment: There's a reason why the works of H. P. Lovecraft are filled with allusions to the _Necronomicon_, the _De Vermis Mysteriis_ of Ludvig Prinn, Friedrich von Junzt's _Unaussprechlichen Kulten_, and Mazur's _Analyse p-adique_.

Comment: Who added the accents on the paper ?